# How do I open a URL from Node in a new browser tab, or go to existing one if its already open?

Tags: node.js, express

When you launch a webpack server it has the neat functionality of opening your URL in new browser window if its not already open in one, but just refreshing the existing one if its already open in a tab (so if you launch multiple times you don't end up with a ton of tabs open).

How do I replicate this in my own command line Node Express server application? I can use open (https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) to open a new tab, but this will ALWAYS open a new tab, so if you keep restarting the server, it will open multiple tabs. Is there anyway (preferably an easy to use package) to check if the URL is already open and refresh an existing tab if its already open, open a new tab its not?

Answer (score 0):

I use this library: `react-dev-utils`,

```
var openBrowser = require('react-dev-utils/openBrowser');
openBrowser('https://stackoverflow.com/');
```

Or you can refer to the [implementation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/25184c4e91ebabd16fe1cde3d8630830e4a36a01/packages/react-dev-utils/openBrowser.js#L65-L86) to write your own.